# How can I mount a secret file into a docker image in a declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins

Currently I have a pipeline working something like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      label 'linux'
      image 'java:8'
      args '-v /home/tester/.gradle:/.gradle'
    }
  }

  environment {
    HOME = '/'
    GRADLE_USER_HOME = '/.gradle'
    GRADLE_PROPERTIES = credentials('gradle.properties')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'cp ${GRADLE_PROPERTIES} ${GRADLE_USER_HOME}/'
        sh './gradlew clean check'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is, `gradle.properties` ends up being put in a more known location on the host system for the duration of the build.

I know that Docker lets me 'mount' files from the host. So I'd like to do this instead:

```
  agent {
    docker {
      label 'linux'
      image 'java:8'
      args '-v /home/tester/.gradle:/.gradle ' +
           '-v ' + credentials('gradle.properties') +
           ':/.gradle/gradle.properties'
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, this ends up running this:

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 1001:1001 -v /home/tester/.gradle:/.gradle -v @credentials(<anonymous>=gradle.properties):/.gradle/gradle.properties -w
```

Is there a way to have it expand it?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to make the environment work for docker args.
My workaround ended up being switching back to scripted pipeline:

```
agent {
  label 'linux'
}
environment {
  GRADLE_PROPERTIES = credentials('gradle.properties')
}
steps{
  script {
    docker.image('java:8').inside('-v /home/tester/.gradle:/.gradle ' +
       "-v $GRADLE_PROPERTIES:/.gradle/gradle.properties"){
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippets work for me. Just define an environment variable using the `credentials` method. And we can access it from the steps command.

BTW, I'm using `podman` as the container engine, and I have to add the `-u root` to the args, otherwise, it will hang after starting the container.

```
stage('Deploy') {
    environment {
        KUBECONFIG = credentials('bec94647-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4300c4d34ae8')
    }

    agent {
        docker {
            image 'alpine/k8s:1.27.4'
            args "-u root"
        }
    }

    steps {
        // KUBECONFIG can be accessed as an environment variable in `deploy.sh`
        sh './deploy.sh'
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the entire pipeline script? ${env.KUBECONFIG} translates to null in the args line. You can use KUBECONFIG in the steps because you will have that in the environment by that point. I'm not sure if it will be available in the args line.

Comment: @PraveenLobo You are right. No need to mount the KUBECONFIG. But I need the `-u root` args, otherwise, it will hang after starting the container.

BTW, I'm using the `podman` as the container engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a chicken and an egg problem. You cannot use a value from an environment variable until the execution starts where the environment variables can be set. You want it before the execution begins. Actually, you want it to be a part of the environment.

You can switch back to scripted block as mentioned in the other answer. If you want to use declarative, you can do it by running the stage in a container.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    HOME = '/'
    GRADLE_USER_HOME = '/.gradle'
    GRADLE_PROPERTIES = credentials('gradle.properties')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent {
        docker {
          label 'linux'
          image 'java:8'
          args "-v /home/tester/.gradle:/.gradle -v ${env.GRADLE_PROPERTIES}:/.gradle/gradle.properties"
          reuseNode true
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh './gradlew clean check'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the double quoted argument for `args` is required so that the environment variable is correctly substituted.

`reuseNode` avoid makes the docker container reuse the workspace from the top level agent where the `gradle.properties` credential file exists and also the default checkout exists. Even if you `skipDefaultCheckout` you will need to `reuseNode` because of the credential file.

If you want multiple stages inside the docker container, then use nested stages by creating `stages` block where the `steps` is.

Jenkins documentation - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent